# Doubt on Lookup relationship

Tags: apex

I have lookup relationship between Account and COntact.

In contact trigger I am querying Account field named as Region and storing it in MAP.
In contact trigger I have added condition, based on Region pick list field of Account I am sending actionid to SAP. 
My question is during contact creation if account lookup is filled then only actionid is flowing. if account lookup is blank no actionid is flowing.

Is account lookup needs to be filled during contact creation?

Regards
G

Comment: Please paste your code, otherwise your question may not attract many answers.

Comment: I cannot post code due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you are sending actionid based on Region field of Account. If a Contact does not have an Account, then you will not get the value for Region field on Account.

So, YES! You will need Account lookup populated IF you want actionid flow to SAP.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts and Accounts has a Lookup relationship so its not always necessary that Contact record has Account. Hence You need to make sure that you have proper null check in your code.

Also, to avoid Query you can have formula on contact that will fetch Account Region to Contact and check whether it contains any value or not.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, Account and Contact always have a Lookup relationship. If you want to make Account as **Required**, you can do that at the **Page Layout** level so that Account is always required to create a new Contact. This way you can always get the value for Region field in your code. You can also put a null check for old records where Account field is not updated.